# LINQ MY SQL QUERY "BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in"

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core

I've got a strange situation.

I've got a column (smallint) that has a single value of 6

[image]

I run using a linq to retrieve records that are Validity_months old.

```
var query = db.table_1
                                .AsNoTracking()
                                .Include(b => b.table_2)
                                .ThenInclude(t => t.table_3)
                                .Where(e => e.Date <= DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(e.table_2.ValidityMonths))
                                .Where(e => e.Date >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(e.table_2.ValidityMonths*-1)));
```

This throws an MySQL Error

Error Code: 1690. BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`database`.`s0`.`validity_months` * (-(1)))'

The query above translates into SQL Query

```
SELECT *
FROM `table_1` AS `s`
LEFT JOIN `table_2` AS `s0` ON `s`.`table_2_id` = `s0`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `table_3` AS `s1` ON `s0`.`table_3_id` = `s1`.`id`
WHERE (`s`.`date` <= DATE_ADD(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL CAST(`s0`.`validity_months` AS signed) month))) 
AND (`s`.`date` >= DATE_ADD(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL CAST(`s0`.`validity_months` * -1 AS signed) month));
```

This ran into MySQL throws the same error. The problem is at

```
CAST(`s0`.`validity_months` * -1 AS signed)
```

How do I negate a field in LINQ. This feels like it's a EFCore bug, but I am not sure yet.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in MySQL, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c5992acba081eed527dd01f7a1739c8).

Comment: Well this is strange, the problem is clearly there and I can reproduce it via code and from MySQL Workbench.  Strange enough, today I rerun the same query and I get no errors. This is a heroku db, could it be something on their side, maybe?